# css flex: выравнивание блоков по одной из стороне

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

Подскажите, как с помощью flex сделать следующее:

есть `div`, содержащий 2 `div`, левый и правый:

```
<div class = 'body'>
    <div class = 'element'>
        <div>LEFT</div>
        <div>RIGHT</div>
    </div>
    <div class = 'element'>
        <div>FIRST</div>
        <div>SECOND</div>
    </div>
    <div class = 'element'>
        <div>LAST</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Но при этом хочется, чтобы если внутри `<div class = 'element'></div>` указан всего один `div`, то он должен отображаться справа и выглядеть (по ширине и высоте) как правый `div` при двухдивной комбинации.

Использовал приведённые ниже стили, но чего-то всё таки не хватает. Подскажите, как надо листы стилей модифицировать?

```
.body {
    width:              100%;

    border:             1px solid #000000;
    background:         #ffffff;
}

.element {
    display:            flex;

    flex-flow:          row nowrap;
    justify-content:    space-between;

    align-items:        flex-start;

    min-height:         38px;

    margin:             5px;
    padding:            0px;
}

    .element:nth-child(2n) {
        background:         lightgoldenrodyellow;
    }

    .element:nth-child(2n+1) {
        background:         lightpink;
    }

.element > div {
    align-self:         center;
}

.element > div:first-child:not(:last-child) {
    width:              175px;

    margin-right:       10px;
    padding-left:       20px;

    font-size:          18px;
    font-family:        Calibri;
}

.element > div:last-child {
    width:              calc(100% - 175px);
}

.element > div:first-child:last-child {
    font-size:          18px;
    font-family:        Calibri;

    background:         red;
}
```

Comment: что-тот не понятно. вы хоть схему нарисуйте для упрощения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю правильно ли понял:

```css
.body {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.element {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  min-height: 38px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.element:nth-child(2n) {
  background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}

.element:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: lightpink;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.element:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: lightpink;
}

.element>div {
  align-self: center;
}

.element>div:first-child:not(:last-child) {
  width: 175px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.element>div:last-child {
  width: calc(100% - 175px);
}

.element>div:first-child:last-child {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  background: red;
  width: calc(100% - 175px - 10px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class='body'>
  <div class='element'>
    <div>LEFT</div>
    <div>RIGHT</div>
  </div>
  <div class='element'>
    <div>FIRST</div>
    <div>SECOND</div>
  </div>
  <div class='element'>
    <div>LAST</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Выглядит так как нужно, сейчас разбираю код и пытаюсь понять, что изменилось

Comment: Не выходит - похоже какой-то стиль выше давит на все этом :(

Comment: нашел что же вы сделали :) `justify-content: flex-end;` в классе `.element:nth-child(2n+1)`, но дело в том, что класс я поставил только для удобства, чтобы видеть разные строки и в принципе он может быть безболезненно убран. кроме того если добавить ещё один `<div class = 'element'>`, чтоб одиночный `div` стал чётным- все перестанет работать. И странно, что когда я свойство `justify-content: flex-end;` ставлю в `.element > div:first-child:last-child` - оно не работает :(